# Issue attaching zip file in javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I was trying to attach a zip file using javamail and was getting the below error :

"com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 552-5.7.0 This message was blocked because its content presents a potential
552-5.7.0 security issue. Please visit http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answe
552-5.7.0 r.py?answer=6590 to review our message content and attachment content
552 5.7.0 guidelines. vb7sm60966875pbc.13 - gsmtp"

Attaching a doc or xls has got no issues. I even believe that attaching a zip file is no different from any other file. Please let me know what is the issue here.

I have also provided the code if needed.

```
public class SendMail {

    @Test
    public static void sendFileEmail()
    {
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String to = "*****@gmail.com";

        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String from = "****@gmail.com";

        // Get system properties
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();

        // Setup mail server
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.debug", "false");

        // Get the default Session object.
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
                {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
                    {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("*****@gmail.com","****");
                    }
                });

        try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                    to));

            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

            // Create the message part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            // Fill the message
            messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");

            // Create a multipar message
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            // Set text message part
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Part two is attachment
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String filename = "XSLTReports.zip";
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Send the complete message parts
            message.setContent(multipart);

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue was some how related to content of the zip file . I changed the zip file and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not set MIME type for the multipart attachements that you send. Try to set it and see

The standard MIME type for ZIP files is application/zip.

Also try application/octet-stream if it dosen't work

Comment: I believe the issue was some how related to content of the zip file . I changed the zip file and it is working fine. Thanks for your response !

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that network access is OK, The problem seems to be network access permission
First : try to ping from your machine to mail server if ok, it's visable to you
Second : try to send simple mail (subject/content)
Third : try to attach simple doc (txt file)